# Just want to know what type of array is this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me what type of variable is this? if it is array what type of array is this? and how we can make this array from code behind.

```
var images = [
   { image: 'http://localhost/SocketV3/Attachments/iNAC/Temp/Post652/PPT/Slides/Slide1.png' }, 
   { image: 'http://localhost/SocketV3/Attachments/iNAC/Temp/Post652/PPT/Slides/Slide2.png' },
   { image: 'http://localhost/socketv3/res/i/common/icn_slideShow.png'}
];
```

Thanks

Comment: there are several ways to make an array like that. maybe update with more detail as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Andy THanks for your prompt reply. I just want to make this dynamic from code behind. var images = '<%= hdnfield.value %> some thing like that. In the code behind i can set the hdnfield with the values exactly as above and can give it to images variable.

Comment: If you just need to generate it in a string server side you can use the same syntax as above. Just generate it server side however is best, as someone mentioned there's usually some JSON methods that can help you. but that syntax works fine to define the array: http://jsfiddle.net/GSXp7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to diminish the answer that is already there, but here is some further explanation.

the `var images = [];` is shorthand notation.
This is equivalent to `var images=new Array();`

Similarly,

```
{image:'http://localhost/SocketV3/Attachments/iNAC/Temp/Post652/PPT/Slides/Slide1.png'}
```

is shorthand for create an Object with one key, called image (the URL is the data).  Classic notation would look more like this:

```
var myObj = new Object();
myObj.image = 'http://localhost/SocketV3/Attachments/iNAC/Temp/Post652/PPT/Slides/Slide1.png';
```

Answer (score 3):

That is an array of objects. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple Array of Objects...

You can use this as follows:

```
var first_url = images[0].image; //will give you the first URL
...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

code behind screams of asp.net

if thats the case then you can use anny json libary for .net

to generate it